# Read and save events to and from a SQL database from ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq

I have the following SQL database table called Calendar:

[image]

I wish to:

1. Load events from the database and pass a List to my web page.
2. Save events to the database.

Note that events are passed to and from the web page as a List and an Array or events.

[image]

The corresponding ajax code for these two functions is as follows:

**GetEvents**

```
          $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "Calendar.aspx/GetEvents",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {

                        var events = $.map(response.d, function (item, i) {
                            var event = new Object();
                            event.id = item.EventID;
                            event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                            event.end = new Date(item.EndDate);
                            event.title = item.EventTitle;
                            event.color = item.EventColor;
                            return event;
                         })
                         callback(events);
                    },

                    error: function (err) {
                       alert('Error');
                    }
                });
             },
```

**SaveEvents**

```
    function save() {
        var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

        var events = $.map(eventsFromCalendar, function (item, i) {
            var newEvent   = new Object();
            newEvent.EventID = item.id;
            newEvent.EventTitle = item.title;
            newEvent.StartDate = item.start;
            newEvent.EndDate = item.end;
            newEvent.EventColor = item.color;
            return newEvent;
        });

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ newEvents: events }),
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "Calendar.aspx/SaveEvents",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Events saved successfully');
            },

            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.text);
            }
        });
        return false;            
    }
```

I see that there are many ways to do  this (ADO, LINQ etc) so I'm not sure the best way to proceed.

**EDIT**

Currently I am loading data manually like so:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Event> GetEvents()
    {
        List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
        events.Add(new Event()
        {
            EventID = 1,
            EventTitle = "EventName 1",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EventColor = "red"
        });
        events.Add(new Event()
        {
            EventID = 2,
            EventTitle = "EventName 2",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EventColor = "green"
        });
        events.Add(new Event()
        {
            EventID = 3,
            EventTitle = "EventName 3",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(11).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EventColor = "blue"
        });
        events.Add(new Event()
        {
            EventID = 4,
            EventTitle = "EventName 4",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(22).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(23).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            EventColor = "yellow"
        });

        return events;
    }
```

I just need to get to the next stage of introducing the database.

Comment: In your DB EventId allows null values but in your model it's an int (if your really want an identity column to be nullable change it to int? in your model). Anyway take a look to Entity Framework. BTW LINQ itself (not LINQ to SQL) doesn't store your data, it's only an option to query them.

Comment: ok I'll change the null value. Ill take a look at Entity Framework also.  Is it the 'best way' to proceed??

Comment: **There is not** a best way. Each approach is different and good for a specific purpose. To give you an answer you should also say (at least): how many users will access that DB? How many records you think it'll contain? Do you have any performance requirement? Any security concern? On which platform it'll run? Entity Framework + Local DB can be a good choice for many cases but it may not be a good option if you have 1000 concurrent accesses and tables with 1.000.000 records. Solutions used to support StackOverflow (for example) aren't "best choice" for a single user PIM...

Answer (score 1):

For most things like this, linq is a good solution. It creates a lot of the classes for you, handles a lot of the work and is nice to work with for the most-part.

So you would:

1) Add a new DBML file to your project
2) In Server Explorer, connect to your database and then drag and drop the Calendar (Events) table onto the DBML file.
3) In code, where "My" is the name of your DBML file:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
var events = (from c in db.Calendars 
              // where c.StartDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
              select c);
return events.ToList();
```

This will return a list of "Calendar"s, because that is the name of your table. You can then filter out the events you want to see with a where clause in your linq and probably re-work some of your code since you no longer need your Event class (Or rename your table to something like CalendarEvent).

That's the basic answer anyway. There may be better approaches depending on your situation, but this should cover most situations and I suspect you're looking for something that just works!

---

To Save the events (as new) - assuming that you are still using your array of Event[] method in your original post, I would loop through your array of Events

```
// Get another data context
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext()    
// Loop
for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
{
    Event event events[i];
    Calendar c = new Calendar();
    c.Property1 = event.Property1;
    c.Property2 = event.Property2;
    /// etc
    db.Calendars.InsertOnSubmit(c);
}

// Submit to the database
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you tell me how I would use your approach to save to the database??